# How to sort two arrays/vectors in respect to values in one of the arrays, using CUDA/Thrust

Tags: c++, sorting, cuda, std, thrust

This is a conceptual question in regards programming.

To summarize, I have two arrays/vectors and I need to sort one with the changes propagating in the other as well, so that if I sort arrayOne, for each swap in the sort - the same thing happens to arrayTwo. Now, I know that std::sort allows you to define a comparison function (for custom objects I assume) and I was thinking of defining one to swap arrayTwo at the same time.

So what I want is - **to sort the two vectors based on values in one of the vectors, using CUDA.**

This is where my uncertainty rises, essentially I want to use the Thrust library to do the sort. Does it support the definition of a custom *comparison* function? If so, I still haven't figured out how to propagate the change in the arrayTwo though (since it will be CUDA based).

I really don't have the time to implement a custom parallel quicksort on CUDA, as much as I should/want to.

*The reason*

Essentially I need to perform sorting and calculation on a bunch of arrays of variables versus a single array (think regression trees). Naturally, I need to do so as quickly as possible, CPU based sort is just not quick enough.

**#UPDATE**

I should emphasize, I have no problems sorting the two on the host, I'm looking for a solution that uses **CUDA**. Thanks.

**#UPDATE 2**

I think I actually got lucky and found the solution since I posted the question,
turns out Thrust actually provides exactly what I'm looking for by default:

```
#include <thrust/sort.h>
  ...
  const int N = 6;
  int    keys[N] = {  1,   4,   2,   8,   5,   7};
  char values[N] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
  thrust::sort_by_key(keys, keys + N, values);
  // keys is now   {  1,   2,   4,   5,   7,   8}
  // values is now {'a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'd'}
```

*taken from http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/QuickStartGuide#Fancy_Iterators*

So, now all I have to do is get two thrust::device_vectors out of the two arrays (that I have to get out of the 2D array). Happy.

Comment: Why don't you just make a vector of pairs and sort based on the first value of the pair? You can certainly pass an appropriate predicate to `thrust::sort` for that purpose.

Comment: when you say pairs - I take it you mean 2D vector? Good idea, but gonna need to cycle through and assign values...unless there's a niftier way maybe?

Comment: No, not a 2D vector, but a vector of pairs... you know, `[(1,A), (3, B), (-11, X), (1, C), ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a vector of integer indexes, initialised to { 0, 1, 2, 3, etc }. Each integer represents one position in your vector. Sort your vector of indexes using a custom comparision function that uses the indexes to refer to vector1. When finished you can use the sorted indexes to reorder vector1 **and** vector2.

But I don't think you can do this reordering in place, so you going to have to copy from vector to vector anyway, so I think Kerrek's suggestion is good too.

Comment: Hmm, I used this technique already (I implemented quicksort on the host and used an index array similar to what you said to propagate changes to both arrays - instead of swapping values, swap logical indexes).

Will this work for the Thrust library though?

Comment: I find it hard to image why not but I have no experience with the thrust library. You had a cenceptual question so I gave a conceptual answer.

Comment: Yes, you did! I just meant that there might be some constraints, since Thrust uses GPU(aswell as host). Thank you for trying to help :-)