# sorting an array, than do the same changes to next array

Tags: cuda, thrust

I´m searching for the simplest and fastest method to sort one array of 10^5 entries and then do the same thing to the next arrays. The arrays are all the same size. 
For Example:

1   a
   6   c
   3   b

I have to sort the first collumn but 6 has to be in the same row as c:

1   a
   3   b 
   6   c

I think I found something, but it looks wierd to implement:

[How to sort two arrays/vectors in respect to values in one of the arrays, using CUDA/Thrust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038838/how-to-sort-two-arrays-vectors-in-respect-to-values-in-one-of-the-arrays-using)

Answer (score 2):

[thrust::sort_by_key](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__sorting.html#ga2bb765aeef19f6a04ca8b8ba11efff24) is exactly what you need.

Here is a sample example from their documentation.

```
#include <thrust/sort.h>
  ...
  const int N = 6;
  int    keys[N] = {  1,   4,   2,   8,   5,   7};
  char values[N] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
  thrust::sort_by_key(keys, keys + N, values, thrust::greater<int>());
  // keys is now   {  8,   7,   5,   4,   2,   1}
  // values is now {'d', 'f', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'a'}
```

You can do the same using device_ptr as well if you have the data on the gpu already.